# ValueError when assigning nan values using DataFrame.at in an integer data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have the following `DataFrame` that consists of integer values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=1, columns=['a','b'], index=[1,2,3])

   a  b
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
```

I would like to set missing values on individual cells, and when I try:

```
df.at[1,'a'] = np.nan
```

Then I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2159, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "pandas/core/frame.py", line 2582, in _set_value
    engine.set_value(series._values, index, value)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 124, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 133, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 570, in pandas._libs.index.convert_scalar
ValueError: Cannot assign nan to integer series
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems function [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) cannot casting integers to float, if set `NaN`s.

For me working [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[1,'a'] = np.nan
print (df)
     a  b
1  NaN  1
2  1.0  1
3  1.0  1
```

@Peter Leimbigler explanation:

> The reason why any type-casting is needed in the first place is because **nan** is of type **float**, and the **int** data type has no support for **nan** or any other missing value. In order for a numeric column to contain **nan**, it must be of type **float**.

@pir explanation:

> **pandas.DataFrame.at** is optimized for specific cell access. Therefore it cannot change the dtype of the column. However, `loc` can.

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.at` is optimized for specific cell access.  Therefore it cannot change the `dtype` of the column.  However, `loc` can.

Comment: To expand on this answer, the reason why any type-casting is needed in the first place is because `nan` is of type `float`, and the `int` data type has no support for `nan` or any other missing value. In order for a numeric column to contain `nan`, it must be of type `float`.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `astype`

```
df.a=df.a.astype(float)
df.at[1,'a']=np.nan
df
Out[43]: 
     a  b
1  NaN  1
2  1.0  1
3  1.0  1
```

Comment: The original data frame could then be redefined to `df = pd.DataFrame(data=1.0, columns=['a','b'], index=[1,2,3])`